# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'float' OR-Tools

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to implement a constraint as follows:

```
routing.solver().Add(capacity_dimension.CumulVar(idx) * routing.ActiveVar(idx) >= capacity_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(v)) * 0.5 )
```

It gives error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'IntVar' and 'float'
```

How can I resolve this?

I tried `capacity_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(v)).Value() * 0.5` on RHS but this kills the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed on https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/LS2vixRsI_Y/m/7NnpJIRyAgAJ

The solver is integral, instead of multiply one side by 0.5, multiply the other by 2.